# Python 2.7 Control Flow

Tags: python, python-2.7, control-flow, password-generator

I'm currently have a little problem:
I'm making a "command" for my bot, a little password generator, currently, I already have the command itself, it'll go like this

```
if Command.lower() == '!pwgen' #First message, the user calls the command
length = Argument[0] #The length he wants, Argument[0] == the length
import os, random, string 
length = 13
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))
password = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length))
messages.Main(password,xSock,BotID)
```

There's my problem, I wanna make sure that, if the argument is empty, I want the password generator to use a default digit, e.g. 12 so the length will be 12 if there's no length given by the user.
Thanks.

Comment: Where's the : on your if statement and where is the indented suite that is supposed to follow it?

Comment: `length = Argument[0] if Argument[0] else 12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have, try:

```
length = Argument[0] if len(Argument)>0 and Argument[0] is not None else 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Argument` is a list you could try to retrieve the value of the length and if the `Argument` is empty i.e. raises an `IndexError` give `length` the desired default value:

```
try:
    length = Argument[0]
except IndexError as error:
    length = 12
```

To handle other types of wrong input e.g. negative values, `None` values, using a simple `if` statement or a ternary assignment should be enough.